# Prevent Pepper's Tablet From Resetting

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

Hello lovely people of SO,

I have a problem with Pepper robot's tablet. I have a simple Choregraphe project which shows a basic HTML. The problem comes when people started talking to the robot. Tablet view constantly resets to default animation.

I've read in SO that the tablet resets every time when the AutonomousLife switches from one activity to another.

Is there a way to stop that behavior? I want my HTML page to be displayed constantly without getting interrupted.

So far I've tried setting the activity as solitary, interactive and no nature. It was the same (Currently it is interactive).

I've also tried to subscribe to AutonomousLife/FocusedActivity and raise an event as seen below. The activity from the image is started manually from Choregraphe.

[image]

Now I see a blink in tablet (Switch to default animation and then return to my tablet view) whenever Pepper switches focus.

This is clearly a workaround to my problem. Is there a right way to do this - to maintain the tablet view without getting interrupted by SwitchFocus and stop that blinking?

Best Regards.

Comment: Have you tried changing the nature of your behavior ? from solitary to interactive ? as seen there: https://youtu.be/xPdNoiuaQag

Comment: @AlexandreMazel Yes sir, I have. It's the same thing. The tablet goes back to default whenever the focus is switched.

Comment: So I don't know... (I forward your question to specialist, let's wait and hope...)

Answer (score 0):

try `ALTabletService._enableResetTablet(0)`
as it is a hidden method, it's not accepted for releases in the store ;)

If you want it system wide, you need to create a service that runs automatically from boot, and executes that command for the ALTabletService when it starts.

You can find instructions for creating services here: http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/dev/tutos/create_a_new_service.html